# Slim 3 no error traceback php

Tags: php, slim, php-7

In slim 2 I used to get error traceback. But in slim 3 it only shows me,

[image]

How do I get the full traceback?

I tried adding ( 'displayErrorDetails' => true ) but still the same problem

I'm new to slim 3

Comment: All points to `displayErrorDetails` being `false`. Are you using `slim-skeleton`? Where exactly are you setting the directive?

Answer (score 0):

Consider toggling `addContentLengthHeader` along with `displayErrorDetails`:

```
<?php
$configuration = [
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true,
        'addContentLengthHeader' => false,
    ],
];
$c = new \Slim\Container($configuration);
$app = new \Slim\App($c);
```

Comment: How could the omission of the `Content-Length` header lead to the simplified error page view being displayed?